# Identifying unused contacts

Tags: administration

I am working on an assignment wherein I have to identify all the contacts where are not used anywhere in our Salesforce org. What could be the best way to approach this? Are there any apps available which can help.

Thanks

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about how "not used" is defined? Does it mean not related to any records besides their Account? Not edited since a certain date? Or something else?

Comment: not related to any records.

Comment: By "related to" do you mean records that they own? Every object in SalesForce has a `LastModifiedById` and `CreatedById` field. This would produce a lot of possible fields you would need to check.

Comment: for e.g. a contact can be used on a case or any custom object. So, i would like to find out all such contacts which are not used in any of the related list (contact obj may have)

Answer (score 1):

1. Get a complete [data export](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_exportdata.htm&language=en_US) for the Contacts and any objects you are interested in that may reference those contacts.
   This will give you zip files containing CSVs with all the columns for those objects, including any Contact references.
2. For each contact Id, do a local text search on the contents of the CSV files. If you find the contact Id anywhere other than on that Contact itself then you know it is referenced at least once.